# Почему скрипт не работает только в Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Скрипт выглядит довольно просто. При в воде в поле .mark он отменяет нажатие клавиши, если это не цифра. Работает в Chrome, Opera и даже IE, а в Firefox цифры не вводятся, то есть игнорируются вообще все клавиши. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему?

```js
$(document).on("keypress", ".mark", function(e){
 if(e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="mark" />
```

Comment: В фаерфоксе `keyCode` всегда равен `0` почему-то

Comment: [MDN говорит](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), что так и задумано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяй e.keyCode на e.which:

```
    $(document).on("keypress", ".mark", function(e){
        if(e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) return false;
    });
```

Comment: Исправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое!) Работает)